# Curl not working with subdomains

Tags: curl

Here is the code I got for now(changed the domain and subdomain names):

```
<?php
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16";
$headers = "Expect:";
$postdata = "username=test&password=test&ref=".base64_encode(md5(time().".com"))."&session=s".md5(time());
$login="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/login.php";
$grab="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/index.php";
function login($url,$data){
        $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        fclose($fp);
        $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($login);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($login);
unset($login);
}                                
function grab_page($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
}
function grab_subpage($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
}
function post_data($site,$data){
        $datapost = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($datapost);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($datapost);
        unset($datapost);
}
login($login, $postdata);
echo grab_page($grab);
?>
```

OK , so ... this code works fine if i navigate any page from http://subdomain.mydomain.com/ but if i try to grab a page from http://anothersubdomain.mydomain.com/ it drops and shows me a white page. var_dump(grab_page($grab)); echoes me string(0) "" . I can't figure out what is the problem and why I can't access that page. I'm googling for a week now and tryied tons of metods and nothing worked, maybe you guys can help me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie file, if it has any saved cookies, as [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) should save cookies when you close the handle.

Change this code in your login function:

```
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
```

to:

```
$response_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response_data;
```

Comment: Still nothing, it gives me a blank page, nothing changed

Comment: i noticed that you try to access global variables from your functions, you need to put global $variable_name in function body, so the function would have access to it, maybe the site doesn't want to give you data with empty agent string. And could you try to put error_notice to E_ALL and use curl_error to see if there is any errors with curl ?

Comment: I've put error_reporting(E_ALL); and global $agent; and if ($response_data === FALSE) echo "CURL failed: " . curl_error($login) . "\n"; and the page still goes white and no error, no warning, nothing.